# Training accuracy stuck at 6% and loss at 2.7 using LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

I am using LSTM for action recognition. My basic LSTM implemented on Keras is getting accuracy of 76% on test data on one dataset(CAD60) but when I use other dataset, my model gets stuck at a loss. Its predicting a single class always.
What can be the problem since I am using the exact framework, features on both the dataset. Even I tried to tune the learning rate change the optimizer but it didn't worked.

```python
model = Sequential() # input has shape (samples, timesteps, locations)
model.add(LSTM(128, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: That a network works with one dataset does not mean it will work with another dataset.

Comment: +1 to @MatiasValdenegro comment. Have you noticed  any significant difference between these two datasets. Could you give us a link to both datasets to analyze a difference?

Comment: CAD60 and MSRDailyActivity3D are very popular activity datasets. You can get them online @StepanNovikov.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I do understand that it is not necessary that my same model will work on all the datasets but atleast my model should learn some actions. It cannot converge to a single class all the time. Right?